# creating an array for a primary key value

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm a personal trainer and I have some programming background but I don't know much about database.. I'm trying to create a program where I can store my clients personal information and especially if they have any health problems and medicines they use so that in case something happens I can quickly find the information needed so what I'm using 
Xampp, and C# ( open to suggestions if I will be more successful with a different language program)

what I want is to create three tables;

1-personal_information (id(primary key) ,first_name,second_name,date of birth, 'and some other information)

2-health_information  ( disease, medicines)

3-size ( kg, and sizes of the body parts like chest, biceps, triceps etc.. and date )

but one client may have more than one disease and may use more than one medicine per a disease) and 
also I want to measure my clients once in 2 months and add the new sizes without losing the previous values

so I need an array of health_information and size per id but how do I do that in mysql? I'm sure that it's something very easy but just can't figure it out

thanks in advance :)

Comment: The concept you are looking for is know as "one to many relationships", have a search for that, you should be able to find plenty of information to get you going in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second table you'll want a column called `personal_information_id` which will correspond to a row in the `personal_information` table.  When you want to retrieve data for specific person execute a query similar to `Select * from health_information where personal_information_id = 12345`.  This will return all the rows in the second table that are related to patient 12345.

Obviously you'll want to do something similar for your `size` table.

Comment: in my second table you meant right? is personal_information_id a primary key? okay,I think I'm getting the hang of it. and than I can use SELECT and JOIN to display the information I need corresponding to  a unique primary key

Comment: Yep, I meant table.  Fixed.  It's actually called a foreign key, which means that it's tied to another table.  You don't have to define it as a foreign key, but it's good practice and many tools (that you may or may not use) can use the information to determine the relationship between the two tables.

Comment: Also, as good practice, be sure to include a primary key for any table you create.

Comment: but what could be a primary key to my health table? is it ok if I make the persona_information_id a primary key and set it not to increment?

Comment: Create a column called id, set it as your primary key and incrementing (just like you did with your first table).  This provides you with an easy way to reference any row in the table (say to update it later).  If you called the `persona_information_id` column a primary key you wouldn't be able to add multiple rows with the same `persona_information_id` (which you'll need to do)